# how to set the background color in html using advanced-html-parser lib from python?

Tags: python, html, html-parser

Iam trying to update the background color of the span using python advanced-htmlParser

I have html page status.html, on which iam trying to parse and updating the color of the span and this updated color should reflect when the page get loaded

```py
# Following are the content of Status.html

<html>
<style type="text/css">
    .Table
    {
        display: table;
    }
    .Title
    {
        display: table-caption;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: larger;
    }
    .Heading
    {
        display: table-row;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .Row
    {
        display: table-row;
    }
    .Cell
    {
        display: table-cell;
        border: solid;
        border-width: thin;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
</style>

<h1>"The dns ip is: " <span id="myID"></span></h1>

    <div class="Heading">
        <div Class="Cell">
            <p>G</p>
        </div>
        <div Class="Cell">
            <p>facebook.com</p>
        </div>
        <div id="test">
            <span id="h" class="Cell">
                <p>H</p>
            </span>
            <span id="e" class="cell">
                <p>E</p>
            </span>
           <span id ="Time" class="Cell">   
                <P> </P>                
             </span>
        </div>


        <div Class="Cell">
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>



</html>

#Blow is the code iam trying to update the backround color of the span_Id 'h'. 

import AdvancedHTMLParser

parser = AdvancedHTMLParser.AdvancedHTMLParser()

path = "D:/Status.html"

parser.parseFile(path)
parser.getElementById('h').style.background="yellow"
```

Expected:
The background of

H should update with the yellow color

Actual:
No update is happening once after execute the script

Appreciate if any one can help on this?

Comment: Can anyone help on this to provide some idea

Answer (score 1):

I used it like this:

```
parser.getElementById("yourElement").setAttribute("style", "background-color:yellow")
```

Comment: Please be more specific why and how your solution works. Please outline the difference of your solution and maybe link some reference or documentation.